# In javascript, how to display a string with end of line characters in the console keeping the "\n"

Tags: javascript

When using `console.log` for a strings that contain end of line characters, the string is broken into several lines.

I'd like to display the screen to the console with the "\n" characters, without modifying the input string.

For instance:

```
let myLines = "Hello\nWorld";
console.log(myLines)
Hello
World
```

I would like the output to be: `"Hello\nWorld"`

Comment: What do you want to log in the case where a string contains an actual slash followed by n, rather than a newline?  Should it log the escaped equivalent, eg `Hello\\nWorld`?

Comment: `console.log("Hello\\nWorld");`

Comment: I cannot change the input string

Comment: Then @CertainPerformance answer will be usefull to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If extra quotes are acceptable, then you can use JSON output (or trim the quotes):

```js
let myLines = "Hello\nWorld";
console.log(JSON.stringify(myLines));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myLines).replace(/^"|"$/g, ''));
```

```
"Hello\nWorld"
Hello\nWorld
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to replace newline characters with a literal backslash followed by a `n`:

```js
let myLines = "Hello\nWorld";
console.log(myLines.replace(/\n/g, '\\n'));
```

Comment: Note that an input of `Hello\nWorld` [is indistinguisable from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPLSA.png) `Hello\\nWorld` - hence my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

It will work,

```
let myLines = "Hello\nWorld"
console.log(myLines.replace('\n','\\n'));
```

Answer (score -1):

just add backslash befor \n :

```js
let myLines = "Hello\\nWorld";
console.log(myLines)
```